# UITextView changeEvent

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I use this simple code to detect any changes of textView.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSUInteger length;
    length = [textView.text length];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", length]);
}
```

is it Possible to increase the size of specific character?

IF User will enter 3 characters, the second one should get increased size + 5.

For example:

```
   if (length == 3)
{

_textView.text = [_textView.font fontWithSize:_textView.font.pointSize + 5];
/// Here is the problem, I don't know how to increase size only for second character


}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use an `NSAttributedString` and set the text view's `attributedText` property.

Comment: @rmaddy do you mean, to use attributedText from interface builder? if I use attributedText from interface builder, i have to type some text, otherwise doesn't take effects

Comment: No, I mean in your code.